# Default value for optional field in a constructor of a generic class

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I'm trying to figure if it's possible (using type declarations alone) to somehow fit a concrete default value for an optional field --- in the context of a generic class, such that the type of this default would be still tied to another required field

```
    type Handler<T> = (msg: T) => boolean;

    type Transformer<T> = (msg: SimpleMsg) => T;

    class Consumer<T> {

        handler: Handler<T>;
        transformer: Transformer<T>;

        constructor(handler: Handler<T>, transformer?: Transformer<T>) {
            this.handler = handler;
            this.transformer = transformer || defaultTransformer
        }

    }
```

Where the default transformer can be something like (just passes the value through):

```
    const defaultTransformer = (msg: SimpleMsg) => {
        console.log('BoringTranfomer! ' + JSON.stringify(msg));
        return msg;
    }
```

At the moment it (rightfully) warns me that `T` could be instantiated with a type that has nothing to do with `SimpleMsg`

I would , therefore - somehow like to define the type of the handler in **terms** of the (type?) of the transformer  (or vice versa?) - and force that type to be `SimpleMsg` in case the transformer is undefined (i.e. not provided)

I know it can be worked around using factory methods or something, where I explicitly define the handler as `Handler<SimpleMsg>`, but I really want to know if it's solvable with types and a single entry point

Thanks!

Comment: Complete side-note but it bothers me `PlainPojo` is a bad name. The **P** in **P**OJO already stands for "plain". So, `PlainPojo` is a "plain plain old JavaScript object"

Comment: I'm like 90% there.  I've got it so that you can only omit the `transformer` if the `handler` takes a `SimpleMsg`, but I haven't got it to infer `T` as `SimpleMsg` in that scenario. https://tsplay.dev/lWYXbm

Comment: Nevermind, we can just set `SimpleMsg` as the default :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Transformer` returns `T` so we cannot possibly create a default without knowing what `T` is.  But you've got the right idea here:

> and force that type to be SimpleMsg in case the transformer is undefined (i.e. not provided)

#### Constructor Overloading

We can do this by overloading the `constructor` function with multiple argument types.  We allow any matching pair of `handler` and `transformer` functions for the same `T` OR just a `handler` which takes a `SimpleMsg`.  Typescript cannot infer the type of `T` in the second case and will return `Consumer<unknown>`, so we have to set the default value of `T` for the class to `SimpleMsg`.

The body of the constructor function only knows the types from the implementation signature, which is the same signature that you had before.  So we do need to assert that the `defaultTransformer` is the right type.

(I renamed `Transformer` to `MsgTransformer` to avoid a duplicate type error that I was getting)

```
class Consumer<T = SimpleMsg> {

    handler: Handler<T>;
    transformer: MsgTransformer<T>;

    // if a transformer is provided, it must match the handler    
    constructor(handler: Handler<T>, transformer: MsgTransformer<T>)
    // if no transformer is provided, then the handler must be for type SimpleMsg
    constructor(handler: Handler<SimpleMsg>)
    // implementation signature which combines all overloads
    constructor(handler: Handler<T>, transformer?: MsgTransformer<T>) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.transformer = transformer || defaultTransformer as MsgTransformer<T>;
    }

}
```

Test cases:

```
// CAN pass just a handler for a SimpleMsg
const a = new Consumer((msg: SimpleMsg) => true);  // <SimpleMsg>
const b = new Consumer(() => true); // <SimpleMsg>
// CANNOT pass just a handler for another type
const c = new Consumer((msg: { something: string }) => true); // error as expected
// CAN pass a handler and a transformer that match
const d = new Consumer((msg: { something: string }) => true, (msg: SimpleMsg) => ({ something: "" })); // generic <{something: string}>
// CANNOT have mismatch between handler and transformer
const e = new Consumer((msg: { something: string }) => true, (msg: SimpleMsg) => ({})); // error as expected
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/aNn3Vm)

#### Edit: Typing an Options Object

In the case where the `handler` and `transformer` are two properties on the same object we would not use overloads.  We would just create a more complicated type for the arguments.

```
constructor({handler, transformer}: Options<T>) {
```

We can use a conditional type which makes `transformer` optional only if the `SimpleMsg` returned for the `defaultTransformer` is assignable to `T`.

```
type Options<T> = SimpleMsg extends T ? {
    handler: Handler<T>;
    transformer?: MsgTransformer<T>; // make optional
} : {
    handler: Handler<T>;
    transformer: MsgTransformer<T>;
}
```

Or we could use a union type.  This is less type-safe because you could manually declare `T` as any arbitrary type when passing a `Handler<SimpleMsg>` (`new Consumer<SomeWrongType>(options)`).  But that seems unlikely to be an issue.

```
type Options<T> = {
    handler: Handler<T>;
    transformer: MsgTransformer<T>;
} | {
    handler: Handler<SimpleMsg>;
    transformer?: never; // need this in order to destructure
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite interesting! I was battling this for hours trying to solve it with types only , didn't think to play with the constructors.... Now, i simplified my use-case for the question but - in my actual use-case i'm passing all the fields wrapped in an opts: {...} object...

How would that affect the solution? would i have to start creating "custom" types to match the various possible inputs in each constructor, with "Omit" and whatnot?

Comment: Ya, seems like it works!
I made one constructor with "Omit" on the transformer and another with a type i created named : "RequireOne" which makes an optional parameter into a required one.

although, that isn't even needed since the fact that transformer is optional in the options object is no longer relevant if I just omit it from it ...

Comment: We don't want it to be optional unless T is the default.  You would use a union of two types `{ handler: Handler<T>; transformer: Transformer<T>; } | { handler: <SimpleMsg>; }`

Comment: Ah thanks, your example makes it much clearer! i couldn't get it to work because i was missing the "never" i guess, i'll try to read up on why it's necessary for destructuring.. thank you so much!

Comment: In order to destructure a property from a union it has to exist on every type in the union.  So we are saying that it "exists" but is optional and can only be `undefined`.

Comment: Just one thing I'm not 100% sure I understand yet - why is the casting necessary? (the expression: "as MsgTransformer<T>") - why can't Typescript deduce that the type would match?

Comment: It's only necessary because we made it optional and we need to assert that the `defaultTransformer` matches the current `T`

Comment: that's what i don't understand - why wouldn't it know that it matches the current T if the only way for the default to be used in the first place - is through the transformer being undefined (which, in turn, narrows T to SimpleMsg -based on our definition)?

Comment: An overloaded function isn't really aware of its overloads.  It needs to work based on just the implementation signature which is usually more vague.  In the case of the options object maybe you could write it such that you don't need to assert, but it can be tricky because narrowing a variable narrows the variable type but not the `T` type.  In the case of the overloads you will always need to assert.